# How to assign FK in forms in django

Tags: python, django

I have passed FK to my views.py function like:

```
def create_user (request,user_id):
    if request.POST:
       form = AllUsersForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
         if form.is_valid():
            form.user_FK_id = user_id  #here i am trying to save FK in table using form object
            form.save()
```

It generates error: `IntegrityError at /createuser/2/ (1048, "Column 'user_FK_id' cannot be null")` It shows that I have used wrong syntax to set FK . How to solve this error, can anyone help me as i am new to django/python? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add to form attributes that way and use them while saving.

If you want to save that way do

```
if form.is_valid():
   obj = form.save(commit=False)
   obj.user_FK_id = user_id
   obj.save()
```